# How to handle file downloads using JavaFX 2.0 WebEngine

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

When using the WebEngine and WebView of JavaFX 2.0 to show some HTML content, I'm not able to handle downloads from the HTML page at all. When I click on any downloadable link nothings happens at all.

Is it possible to handle downloads in JavaFX 2.0 WebView/WebEngine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Download functionality is currently not implemented in WebView.
You can implement it yourself by monitoring the location property of the WebView and then creating appropriate code to perform the download.

```
webView.getEngine().locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String oldLoc, String newLoc) {
    // check if the newLoc corresponds to a file you want to be downloadable
    // and if so trigger some code and dialogs to handle the download.
  }
});
```

An example of code to handle a download from JavaFX can be found in this [zenjava blog entry](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/14/file-downloading-in-javafx-2-0-over-http/). Edit: This blog page does not exist anymore. Here is the [latest archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20150420225304/http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/14/file-downloading-in-javafx-2-0-over-http/) of this blog page.

Downloads in web browsers are often triggered by http [content-type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) or [content-disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt) headers and can be based upon a mime-type/file extension mapping.  The above scheme will only work for a file extension mapping where the file extension is derived from the location.  For handling downloads based on a content-type or content-disposition header you would likely need to implement your own java.net url connection handler.

To get this functionality implemented in the core JavaFX libraries you could check the [JavaFX Jira](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) for a feature request around this and, if it is not there, create a new feature request.